# Create dataframe from list in Rproj

Tags: r, lapply

I have an issue that really bugs me: I've tried to convert to Rproj lately, because I would like to make my data and scripts available at some point. But with one of them, I get an error that, I think, should not occur. Here is the tiny code that gives me so much trouble, the R.proj being available at: https://github.com/fredlm/mockup.

```
    library(readxl)
list <- list.files(path = "data", pattern = "file.*.xls") #List excel files

#Aggregate all excel files
df <- lapply(list, read_excel)
for (i in 1:length(df)){
  df[[i]] <- cbind(df[[i]], list[i])
}
df <- do.call("rbind", df)
```

It gives me the following error right after "df <- lapply(list, read_excel)":

> Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim =
>   shim,  :    path[1]="file_1.xls": No such file or directory

Do you know why? When I do it old school, i.e. using 'setwd' before creating 'list', everything works just fine. So it looks like lapply does not know where to look for the file when used in a Rproj, which seems very odd...

What did I miss?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you post the information from your RProj file?

Comment: what kind of information do you need? Is that a specific file?

Comment: The RProj is just a configuration file somewhere, I think it might help to have its contents available.

Comment: Hi @TARehman, sorry for the *very* late response. I edited my post and added a link to GitHub so you have all the required info. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi there,
Nobody around here can help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a non-stackoverflower, a solution was found. It's silly, but 'list' was missing a directory, so lapply couldn't aggregate the data. The following works just fine:

```
list <- paste("data/", list.files(path = "data", pattern = pattern = "file.*.xls"), sep = "") #List excel files
```